# how to code a program that uses xbox controller under linux

Tags: c, linux, xbox360

Currently I am an IT student, and I want to make a game as my semestral work. I want to make a *Geometry Wars* clone purely in *C* (cause we are bound to C, ergo no C++/C#, ***only C and OpenGL***), and when it will be done, I want to publish that as open-source game for Linux/Mac/PC. I want to ask, how can I use Xbox360 controller ***(wired)*** as gaming input device? I learnt after some research that XInput does the stuff, but is that really multiplatform thingy? I am curious what do you use folks for coding Xbox controller input in C under linux.

Comment: I assume you're using a normal Wireless XBox 360 controller with one of these: http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Hardware/Controllers/Pages/XboxWirelessGamingReceiverforWindows.aspx/ ?

Comment: Does it not appear as a standard USB controller? (I don't know)

Comment: okay, maybe I ask a little bit different...how can I capture the input from an USB device (xbox360 controller now) via C programming language? I have never worked with USB peripherals for now in C

Comment: Note that you can't really create much using only C and OpenGL, as neither C nor OpenGL concerns itself with windowing, input and other platform specific stuff. Use libSDL to cover up that, which also provides a cross platform joystick and keyboard API. Linux has drivers which will make the xbox controller appear as a joystick, and you can map buttons to look like key presses.

Comment: I think I summed up my problem in a really dumb way, never mind, I learned from this :D I meant only, that I can use only C and extend it with external libs, like OpenXX stuff or that. I will try out that SDL thingy, maybe it will work, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy working out the right question to ask is half the battle ;)

Comment: totally agree with you @therefromhere

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look and find some information about this and I've found:

1. use the [SDL library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)
2. use the functions in the github [linux/joystick.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/joystick.h)

I've no idea how to do any of this, but a good point to begin is studying what is SDL, in [there](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryGameController) or the github above.

**A workarround:**

Get a look on [this](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/releases/tag/2.21) repo on github. It's a Linux substitute for JoyToKey. You can use it to bind keys for your controller, and bind keys like CRTL+SPACE or bind some button to a virtual keyboard.